# Exception: AttributeError: type object 'CognitiveSearchClient' has no attribute 'client'

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following class:

```
import os
import pinecone
import openai
import time
import logging
import traceback
import base64

from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient

class CognitiveSearchClient:
    """CognitiveSearchClient  class."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        api_key: str,
        endpoint: str,
        index_name: str,
    ):
        """Initialize the Pinecone object.

        Args:
            api_key: The Pinecone API key.
            environment: The Pinecone environment.
        """
        try:

            credential = AzureKeyCredential(api_key)
            self.client = SearchClient(endpoint=endpoint,
                                index_name=index_name,
                                credential=credential)        
        except ImportError:
            raise ValueError("Could not  authenticate with Azure Search. ")
        
    @classmethod         
    def KeywordSearch(self, query:str):
        """Searches for a keyword in the index.

        Args:
            query: The keyword to search for.

        Returns:
            The search results with decoded metadata.
        """
        results = self.client.search(search_text=query)

        for result in results:
            if "@search.metadata_storage_path" in result:
                metadata_path = result["@search.metadata_storage_path"]
                decoded_metadata_path = base64.b64decode(metadata_path).decode("utf-8")
                result["@search.metadata_storage_path"] = decoded_metadata_path

        return results
```

and I am trying to use it from a different project:

```
@app.get("/KeywordSearchWithCognitiveSearch")
def KeywordSearchWithCognitiveSearch(api_key:str, 
                    endpoint: str,
                    index_name: str,
                    query: str,
                    ):
    client =  CognitiveSearchClient(api_key=api_key, endpoint=endpoint, index_name=index_name) 
    docs = client.KeywordSearch(query=query)
    return docs
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Exception: AttributeError: type object 'CognitiveSearchClient' has no attribute 'client'
```

What am I missing?